# Iterating through and joining values in json

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that I'm trying to iterate through to join file paths housed inside but I keep having issues:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "Mississippi",
      "folder": "H:\\Data\\Mississippi",
      "zFeatures": [
        {
          "name": "Land_Use",
          "file": "MS_LandUse.shp",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

In this case I'd like to join `file` to `folder` so my output would be: `"H:\\Data\\Mississippi\\MS_LandUse.shp"`. I do have hundreds of other files that also need to be joined so I need to iterate through this json.

I've tried iterating top down but that failed

```
with open("filoc.json", "r") as i:
    filoc = json.load(i)

for files in filoc['files']:
    for folder in files['folder']:
        for zFeatures in files['zFeatures']:
        #This is where I'm stumped, I feel like I'm already doing it wrong.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on to something. It's a shame that you didn't exactly specify what your problem is. First, let me correct that JSON data (it's corrupt):

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "Mississippi",
      "folder": "H:\\Data\\Mississippi",
      "zFeatures": [
        {
          "name": "Land_Use",
          "file": "MS_LandUse.shp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can combine `os.path.join` and `os.path.abspath` to join and make sure the path is correct by doing something along the lines of:

```
import os, json

with open("test.json", "r") as i:
    filoc = json.load(i)

for file_info in filoc['files']:
    print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(file_info['folder'], file_info['zFeatures'][0]['file'])))
```

This assume that there's only one file under `zFeatures` tho. If there are multiple, just do:

```
for file_info in filoc['files']:
    for f_obj in file_info['zFeatures']:
        print(...(file_info['zFeatures'][f_obj]['file']))
```

But I'm assuming this blob is per-file.

Lastly, beware of [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) - if passed a windows path on a Linux machine - it will generate a wonky path. If the paths are mixed, just skip `abspath()` and hope that paths aren't mixed or correct for it when they are.

Comment: Using `os.path` is best as well to avoid most of the many pathing gotchas across different OS.

Answer (score 1):

After changing your sample json input file into valid JSON:

```json
{
    "files": [
        {
            "name": "Mississippi",
            "folder": "H:\\Data\\Mississippi",
            "zFeatures": [
                {
                    "name": "Land_Use",
                    "file": "MS_LandUse.shp"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's probably the simplest way to do what you want:

```
import json
import os


with open("filoc.json", "r") as inp:
    filoc = json.load(inp)

    for file_metadata in filoc['files']:
        folder = file_metadata['folder']
        filename = file_metadata['zFeatures'][0]['file']
        print(os.path.join(folder, filename))
```

Which prints this processing the sample input file:
`H:\Data\Mississippi\MS_LandUse.shp`

Since there could be more than one `"zFeatures"` file, you may want/need to nest another `for` loop inside of the `for file_metadata in filoc['files']:` loop to process each of them individually. Here's what I mean:

```
with open("filoc.json", "r") as inp:
    filoc = json.load(inp)

    for file_metadata in filoc['files']:
        folder = file_metadata['folder']
        for feature in file_metadata['zFeatures']:  # Added 'for' loop.
            filename = feature['file']
            print(os.path.join(folder, filename))
```